# Microsoft Bot Framework - Proactive message, suspend current dialog

Tags: bots, botframework

I've created a simple news bot which sends updates to a user every 24 hours. I've created a callback controller which handles requests from an external service, processes the resumptionCookie, then sends a carousel of articles with two buttons to the user. One of the buttons opens a browser window, the other should trigger a new dialog (OptionsDialog).

Is this implementation correct? and is it possible to suspend any active dialog, whilst the user interacts with the news article message? For example, if i'm going through a particular dialog, then suddenly I get a news alert, is it possible to suspend the current dialog, to allow the user to update the options of the alerts (almost like the news alert is outside the normal dialog flow), then once they've finished they'll return to the previous dialog. Hopefully, the question is clear enough. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CallbackController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(ResumptionCookie resumptionCookie)
    {
        var activity = (Activity)resumptionCookie.GetMessage();

        var reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Text = "We found 7 news articles that match your criteria";
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
        {
            new ThumbnailCard
            {
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                {
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "BBC", null, "http://www.bbc.co.uk"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "Update Options", null, "Update Options")
                }
            }.ToAttachment()
        };

        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

        return Ok(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

This is my Main dialog

```
[Serializable]
public class MainDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(ProcessMessage);
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessage(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var response = await result;

        if (response.Text.Equals("Update Options", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Call(new OptionsDialog(), FinishMainDialog);
        }
        else
        {
            PromptDialog.Confirm(context, ProcessChoice, "Do you wish to continue?");
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessChoice(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
    {
        var choice = await result;

        if(choice)
        {
            context.Call(new DialogOne(), FinishMainDialog);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Done(true);
        }
    }

    private async Task FinishMainDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

Here is my frequency dialog

```
[Serializable]
public class OptionsDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("You can update your to options here");

        context.Wait(ProcessMessage);
    }

    public async Task ProcessMessage(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {

        await context.PostAsync("Hello, World!");
        context.Done(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when notification is received ? Bot fails ? Or ?

Comment: @BobSwager the notification renders correctly, my issue is that i'm not sure if I'm correctly handing the response when a user clicks the 'Update Options' button on the notification.

Comment: You can use Emulator and debug. You can see your flow. If you get stuck then write comment and we will try to fix it together.